# Unable to run tar command - invalid option -- '▒'

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, command, tar

I've run into a problem while running a tar script.  I am getting an invalid option, as shown in the screenshots, that is stopping the script running.  I don't get why however as the command worked outwith the script.  Can anyone help me?

The script:

[image: The script]

The error:

[image: The error]

Answer (score 27):

Thanks to Paul R I have an answer.  No idea how to mark his comment as the answer though so here it is:

> Some older versions of tar don't like the `-` at the start of the
>   commands - try `tar cvpfz ....` – Paul R 5 mins ago

Answer (score 17):

Are you copy and pasting the command, instead of hand-typing it in terminal?

In my case, I was getting:

`tar: invalid option -- '�'`

I was pasting into terminal, the command from a raw text file, which I had copied from a tutorial:

`tar –xvzf bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`

I hand-typed the entire command:

`tar -xvzf bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`

and it worked. I suspect it was something like an extra space character or a `-` or similar which was not working.

Comment: I got the same issue too, in my case changing the filename of tar gz file resolve this error. probably stale tar cmd doesn't allow some character for a filename?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i tried `chmod 777 'FILE_NAME'` for unlock the file.

Then installing, it works well!